# jQuery draggables and multi-touch

Tags: jquery, touch, draggable, multi-touch

I've been developing an HTML 5 game on my MacBook using Safari. It uses jQuery and jQuery UI and heavily depends on draggables and droppables.

It works well on the desktop.

I got it to a point where I felt it was solid and decided it was finally time to take a look at it on a touch device so pointed my iPad at my local server and...*slaps forehead*...that's right...jQuery UI isn't touch enabled! D'oh!

A quick google, however, turned up this great script: http://touchpunch.furf.com/

This was an incredibly easy fix. It translates touch events into mouse events so you can keep on using jQuery UI as-is. This works wonderfully.

Except...I can only drag one item at a time. Dragging one draggable is fine, but once I trigger a second touch event on the device, it kills the first. Eventually I wanted to enable the ability to drag multiple items at once.

Is there a solution here with my current set of tools, or did I just take a seriously wrong turn way back at using jQuery UI and jQuery draggables by default? If I did take a wrong turn, is there a better way to go about this with jQuery? Does jQuery mobile support multi-touch draggables?

UPDATE:

After doing a bit more research, including Omar's link, I wonder if I'm after the wrong thing. I don't need multi-touch gestures (pinch, rotate, multi-finger swipe, etc.) but rather I just need to be able to trigger two draggables.

It appears that Mobile Safari fires some event on a second touch if one is already active and that event is 'telling' the first draggable to stop.

I wonder if there's an workaround short of full multi-touch gesture support.

Comment: no, jqm doesn't offer a built-in multi-touch support. you need a plugin like hammer.js